# AWS Dynamo Rolllback Timeout

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

If i have AWS lambda that writes to Dynamo, will it rollback after a timeout?

Two scenario's:

1. I update the dB in a transaction one item at a time?
2. I send a batch update (chunked at 25 records) wrapped in a transaction ?

I think that since each batch update and each single update is an atomic transaction, it will not rollback.

How can i roll back say update of 100 records if the lambda times out on record 99?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about a lambda timeout when updating records, reduce the number of items each lambda invocation updates to give yourself plenty of headroom. You can send all item keys needing an update into an SQS queue, then have a second lambda pull from the queue and update a batch of records. If your lambda execution times out on any batch of records, the SQS message will be returned to the queue and it can be processed again.